# How to access bluetooth camera via android app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, esp32

I want to be able to transfer snapshots and record photos and videos to the application with a Bluetooth camera via the Android app. I found some code related to this topic, but I could not test it because it was coded in old versions and these versions are no longer supported. Which library should I use or which function should I use to make this application?

Old version codes:
[How to show camera preview on other device over Bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146652/how-to-show-camera-preview-on-other-device-over-bluetooth) -
[BluetoothCameraAndroid](https://github.com/sujithkanna/BluetoothCameraAndroid)
[BluetoothRemoteCamera](https://github.com/shivarajp/BluetoothRemoteCamera)

Comment: Do you mean to transfer data between two Android devices as it's done in the link you posted?

Comment: Actually, i want to transfer data between esp32-cam module and android phone.

Comment: Do you program the camera or does it use a stock software?

Comment: Obviously I am not programming a camera. I have a camera connected to the esp32-cam module and I program the module with arduino. I programmed the module similar to the code in the link below.   (https://github.com/0015/ThatProject/blob/master/ESP32_BT_CLASSIC/ESP32CAM_BT_SERIAL/ESP32CAM_BT_SERIAL_ARDUINO_IDE/ESP32CAM_BT_SERIAL_ARDUINO_IDE.ino)

Comment: Well you have to pair the device and then establish a [bluetooth socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket). You have to design your own protocol to talk to the Arduino. On the Android device you should find a way to play videos directly from RAM. Because writing it to a temporary file wears out the flash memory. If there's no API (to play videos from RAM) then one way is to create a local TCP HTTP socket and play a local URL. see [setDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Also see [memfd_create](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) and [setDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)). Don't know if this API is available on Android.

Comment: Are you sure an Arduino and Bluetooth is fast enough? Because you have to encode the video on the Arduino and camera drones normally use WiFi not Blueooth.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did the project in flutter and bluetooth worked fast enough. But I can't use flutter because I have ML codes to embed (I can't use firebase because I need to run ML codes without internet connection).